# Trouble with making file path

Tags: c++

I'm trying to load multiple files from a directory with for loop but I keep getting access violation and very strange path strings.

Here is what I get in my path variable:

```
data/ÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌÌ0ùB
```

and here is the code which makes that path:

```
Animation::Animation(std::string name, int framecount)
{
    char path[MAX_PATH];
    char *ext = ".bmp";
    frames = new SDL_Surface*[framecount];
    for (int k = 0; k < framecount; k++) {
        frames[k] = NULL;
        sprintf(path, "data/%s/f%i%s", name, k, ext);
        SDL_Surface *img = load_image(path);
        memset(&path[0], 0, sizeof(path)); // Clear tmp
    }

    maxFrames = framecount;
    currentFrame = 0;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: use `snprintf` instead of `sprintf` to avoid a buffer overflow. Also, the `memset` has no use since you overwrite it with the next `sprintf`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `c_str()` after `name`

```
sprintf(path, "data/%s/f%i%s", name.c_str(), k, ext);
```